# Magnetization subspace and Hamiltonian representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

A follow-up question of the subspaces of 4-electrons: assume the magnetization of the system is conserved (the number of total spin-up $(\uparrow)$ particles is conserved), say 1, for example. Then the eigenvalue of M is 1. I'm wondering if I want to write the total Hamiltonian matrix (it should be 4 by 4 in this case), should H look like the identity matrix? If not, what should that be? (The Schrodinger's equation is: $H|\downarrow\uparrow\downdownarrows⟩=M|\downarrow\uparrow\downdownarrows⟩, M = 1$.)

Also, if M = 2, the dimension of H should be $C_4^2=6$. How can I write the 6 by 6 Hamiltonian matrix in that case? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it definitely would *not* look like the identity matrix! Are you *sure* this is not an extended homework question?

*M=1* means *m=-1* a combination of the spin 2 and the three spin 1 states.  It appears your Hamiltonian is proportional to the total $\hat j_z$, which commutes with $\hat j \cdot \hat j=(j)(j+1) 1\!\! 1$, so it does not mix the 4 multiplets involved, so it is diagonal in that 4-dimensional space, and does not mix the subspaces. But there is no reason for all 4 diagonal entries  to be  the same. You do understand that in your Schroedinger equation example, your wrote a particular linear combination of the energy eigenvector, and this would only obtain if the hamiltonian *were* a multiple of the identity: If you have worked the angular momentum subspaces, you have seen this.

Likewise, *M=2* means *m=0*, as in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579299/subspace-and-symmetry-of-4-electrons/579362#579362), and the 6 states should not mix with each other, so the diagonal 6x6 matrix would have, in principle, different entries along its diagonal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! By 'does not mix the subspace', do you mean in this case I don't need to consider the superposition of each possible state? Could you give me some hint on how to figure out the diagonal entries in the Hamiltonian matrix? Should I find each of then from the Schrodinger's equation? Thanks!!

Comment: This is not a homework question, I was just trying to understand the Hamiltonian representation in different subspaces by using some examples:)

Comment: The state you wrote straddles all 4 subspaces. As a "good faith gesture", write all 4 orthogonal states, each in a separate subspace. Nobody can figure out the diagonal entries in the Hamiltonian: you have freedom there. Diagonal means it does not mix the 4 subspaces, but that's all your know!

Comment: Thanks!! But for the 4-site Heisenberg Hamiltonian example (no external field), where $H = \sum_{i<j=0}^3J_{ij}\vec\sigma_i\cdot\vec\sigma_j$, can I determine the diagonal entries?

Comment: Of course, but that is a different question. If all Js were the same, for total spin S, you'd have something like $H=(4S(S+1)-12)/2J $, or something...